# Android : Retrofit and using dynamic URLS

Tags: android, retrofit

Good morning.  I am pretty new to Retrofit, taking on the project from another.  We need to talk to a API that uses a code in the url for each call
E.g http://www.example.com/CODE/review

I thought I would try the obvious but Retrofit is complaining about **Attribute value must be a constant**

```
public interface ApiService{
        public static final String ref = getRefCode();

        //TODO: Use ref number to identify users
        @Headers({
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Content-Type: application/json"})
        @GET("/" + ref + "/RepairStatus")
        void getRepairStatus(@Header("If-None-Match") String ifNoneMatch, RestCallback<RepairStatusResponse> callback);


        @Headers({
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Content-Type: application/json"})
        @POST("/" + ref + "/Review")
        void postReview(@Body ReviewRequest reviewRequest);

    }
```

Sorry if I am missing the obvious :)

Comment: Don't you do something like this:
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);

Comment: You where correct, please post as Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you do something like this:

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users") List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```